# React native paper textinput component alignment issue

Tags: javascript, textinput, react-native-paper

In textInput I'm getting an issue:

```
<TextInput
        theme={{ colors: { primary: '#27B6CC' } }}
        style={{ marginTop: 15, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        error={Boolean(props.touched.Brand_Name && props.errors.Brand_Name)}
        label='Brand Name'
        mode='outlined'
        value={props.values.Brand_Name}
        onChangeText={props.handleChange('Brand_Name')}
/>
```

[image]

I'm getting this issue from `"react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",`